# GeoServer: add style to MULTILINESTRING

Tags: geoserver

I am new on GeoServer, I have made a layer from my geometry data
[image]

Now I am trying to add a background to it so I added a green default style :

[image]

but my layer is like this:

[image]

How can I fix it? My data is multiline string

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Lines do not have an area to fill with colour. It worked for the smaller rings in your screenshot because the rendering engine is converting your lines to polygons.

The larger rings appear to consist of multiple lines (rather than one continuous one), hence the straight segments in the green fill where the rendering engine has attempted to close the lines into polygons.

To accomplish "filling" all the lines, you will likely have to dissolve the lines (keeping disjoint features separate) and re-upload the layer. However, that seems a bit hacky. It is probably better to convert your lines to polygons and use the GeoServer styles as they are intended.